# Display all class methods in Cedet

Tags: emacs, cedet

Is there a way to display only C++ class declarations (methods and attributes) in cedet?
Sort of speedbar but limited to a specific class.

Comment: Standard completion on object, will display everything... And Semantic have function to fetch functions & variables

Comment: @AlexOtt Maybe I didn't setup cedet correctly, but the auto-completion as I type only gives me one completion at the time for a specific type or variable name. For example, if I type 'MyC' it will auto-complete to 'MyClass' and then as I keep hitting TAB I will see other completions. What I need is to type a valid class name and popup all the methods and attributes for that class in a separate buffer.

Comment: `semantic-analyze-possible-completions` (`C-c , l`) should provide all possible completions if you'll put, `.`, `->`, or `::` after name of class.  I think, that you can look into source code of this function to find, how it calculates completions. I think, that this is `semantic-tag-type-members` function

Comment: @AlexOtt You're correct, semantic-analyze-possible-completions works! It opens a new buffer with all class members and attributes. Thanks.